# Arquillian testing: cannot remove dependencies to slf4j from the embedded glassfish

Tags: maven, slf4j, jboss-arquillian, maven-dependency

I'm creating a java EE integration test suite with arquillian and junit in a multi pom maven project. In the main pom I am including both the embedded glassfish required by arquillian and the slf4j library required by my project. The embedded glassfish contains a reference to slf4j itself, so I am trying to remove it by specifying an exclusion inside the dependency, as specified in http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, whenever I start the tests, the slf4j dependency pops magically out

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/panda/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.2/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/panda/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.5.10/slf4j-simple-1.5.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Probably I'm missing something... What should be the right approach to remove the dependency to slf4j contained in the glassfish embedded jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Since the `glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.jar` is an uber jar which contains the `org/slf4j/*` inside.

You can extract your `C:/Users/panda/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.2/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.jar` to see it further. Not only the `slf4j` but also every required packages are inside as well.

If you look at its [pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.2/glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.2.pom), there is no any dependency to the `slf4j` as well. It is a reason why you cannot exclude it via the dependency exclusion.

Comment: Found it, switched to glassfish 4, now everything works. Thanks again, your answer allowed me to prune out of my resolution tree a big branch of banging head against the wall.

Comment: The beauty of embedded containers :)